# How to connect Ubuntu 20.04 minimal instance to a L2TP vpn?

Tags: 20.04, network-manager, vpn, ubuntu-minimal, l2tp

I am trying to connect an Ubuntu minimal instance to a VPN. I have installed network-manager-l2tp and have configured the connection as so:

```
[connection]
id=vpn
uuid=7cb18238-9976-4836-8b7e-ff1ebc60299f
type=vpn
autoconnect=false
permissions=

[vpn]
gateway=REDACTED
ipsec-enabled=yes
ipsec-psk=REDACTED
password-flags=0
user=REDACTED
service-type=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.l2tp

[vpn-secrets]
password=REDACTED

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
ip6-privacy=0
method=auto

[proxy]
```

Following the few other SE posts, I made sure that network-manager was managing my interface.

```
nmcli dev
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION
ens3    ethernet  connected  ens3
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --
```

However, whenever I try to enable the VPN connection, this is the result:

```
sudo nmcli con up vpn
Error: Connection activation failed: Could not find source connection.
```

The only other thing I can find is configuring a default route. But since this is the only physical interface, of course it already has a default route.

Comment: Yeah, I have no problem doing anything over the network other than connecting to the vpn with that error.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the following NetworkManager source code where it outputs the `Could not find source connection` error you are getting :

- https://github.com/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/blob/1.30.2/src/core/nm-manager.c#L5119

the only way it can happen is if the `parent` connection isn't set which in turn is because `priv->primary_connection` isn't set. Which seems to indicate NetworkManager doesn't know what the primary connection is for some reason in your case.

For some primary connection debugging, if you run `nmcli monitor` and then pull out the Ethernet cable, wait a few seconds and then put it back, you should see the following messages amongst others:

- There's no primary connection
- 'Wired connection 1' is now the primary connection